# dialog public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) not getting called

Tags: android

I created a custom `dialog` and I tried to  override `public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` but this is not getting called while the button is getting clicked.

Comment: why do you need dispatchTouchEvent ?

Comment: In my custom dialog it's working just fine, I get all 3 events when I click ok or cancel button. Can you post some code of your implementation?

Comment: okButton.setOnClickListener, why would one be setting an onTouchListener?

Comment: have you set touchlistener on button??

Comment: But I did also check if it matters and it didn't.